# Problems with Compiling Qt Creator Source Code with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: qt, compilation

I am trying to compile the Qt Creator source code using Visual Studio 2019 following the instructions on Github, and the following issue occurred:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSxhu.png)

The command I referenced is ：

**cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G Ninja "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/Qt;/path/to/llvm" \path\to\qtcreator_sources**

When I compile with *-G ninja * ， I run qt-creator.exe Ok! But I can't get .sln file.
When I compile without *-G ninja * ， it's noy Ok!

I have no idea! It Just  tips me that could not find plugins!

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the path for Qt to load the plugin is incorrect. At this point, the code has already been compiled, so we can debug it and modify some of the code in the loading path.